# Button tag and vertical alignment with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, button, vertical-alignment

I have some buttons which contain text. I am trying to style it so that the text **inside** the buttons is vertically aligned to the top as if it were a div, instead of in the middle.

I have tried a few bits such as making it display: table-cell which I saw somewhere, but no joy.

The text is dynamic so it could be 1 word, or a short paragraph, so would prefer not to use line-height or similar.

**CSS**

```
button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;

    background: #EBEBEB;
    color: #124191;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<button>Text</button>

<button>Some more text that may go onto multiple lines like this...</button>
```

**So my question:** How do I vertically align text inside a button to the top?

http://jsfiddle.net/DNcR6/1/

Comment: Perhaps stop using a `button` and use a `div` instead?

Comment: @Paulie_D which would be in my case semantically incorrect, hence the button :)

Comment: A div has no semantics...so it doesn't matter. What would your 'button' do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with fixed widths, just add some padding to the bottom:

```
 button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  background: #EBEBEB;
  color: #124191;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DNcR6/2/

Comment: as per the title the content is dynamic, so I dont know if its 1 word, or a short paragraph

Comment: I would suggest using a div instead of a button in that case

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the button's text, if you set the bottom padding to match the button height, it will shove the text as far up as possible. So `padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;` would do it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DNcR6/3/)**

Comment: so is padding really the only way to get the text to the top?  I saw a post that used a very large line-height to get it to the bottom reliably but it doesn't help getting it to the top

Comment: @ChrisM - Plus changing the line height for multi-line text won't work.

Comment: true that.  so padding it is!

Comment: awarding this to @eric as he got in with it first